# Only perform function if loading a new page

Tags: jquery

I have a menu that contains links such as:

```
<a href="https://someurl.com/home/">Home</a>
<a href="https://someurl.com/about/">About</a>
<a href="https://someurl.com/about/#services">Services</a>
```

I have a preloader element that fades in and out between page loads and is activated when a link is clicked. So if you are on the home page and you click on Services, the preloader element fades in, the About page loads, scrolls down to the #services anchor, and then the preloader element fades out.

I have it set where if the href starts with # like `href="#services"` the preloader won't load since the page is just scrolling to the anchor.

The problem is, if you are on the About page, and click on Services, the preloader loads because the href doesn't start with #.

**Question: How can I avoid the preloader from loading on anchor elements that stay on the same page?**

Comment: What do you mean "is activated when a link is clicked"? Do you have an event listener for that?

Comment: @JonathanWilson Yes, I do.

Comment: That's where you compare the current URL with the destination URL as I described in my answer

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to compare the destination to your current URL, and only display the loader they differ.

Consider comparing the hash-free versions of your current URL and your destination.

ie. to get the current URL without the hash:

`window.location.href.split('#')[0]`

Comment: Thank you, yes this would be helpful im sure, I just don't really know how to check or compare... I already have a class `no-preloader` that can be added to disable the preloader on specific links. So I was hoping something like this would work:

`$("a[href*='" + window.location.href.split('#')[0] + "']").addClass("no-preloader");`

Comment: Alternatively, a way to just remove anything before the # if it's linked to the current page would work well.